# Custom network devices naming scheme

Tags: networking, udev

I have an ubuntu image to be used on virtual machines. I don't know in advance how many NICs would be used for the machines. I need all network interfaces to get names from a predefined list.

For example, with a file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/nic_names
my_first_nic
my_second_nic
```

I need to get

```
$ ip link list
1: lo
2: my_first_nic
3: my_second_nic
```

How can I configure the image to support my custom network devices naming scheme?

Comment: It would probably helpful to state _why_ you need this. The file requirement places a restriction on possible solutions, but it might not even be applicable. Also add if you can extend "whatever you are doing" with scripts etc.

Comment: Use `udev` rules to give the network interfaces persistent names. Make the rule(s) so as to fit your scheme/list, or generate them from the list of appropriate. Also think about how MAC addresses fit into whatever you want to do.

Comment: If you don't know how many NICs might be present how do you expect a static predefined list to be sufficient?

Comment: @Seth I know that amount will not exceed some predefined number.

Comment: @mtak I use software which requires the interfaces to be named in a specific manner. I can use scripts for this renaming. I tried to add `ip link set $old name $name`, but couldn't ssh after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/71-rename-ifs.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="net" ATTRS{ifindex}=="2" NAME="my_first_nic"
SUBSYSTEM=="net" ATTRS{ifindex}=="3" NAME="my_second_nic"
...
```

`ifindex==1` is skipped since it is a loopback interface.